# Event on tiles start loading in Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for a way to detect if tiles of google maps v3 are loading or and event which triggers when tiles start loading.

My UI is build as follows:

There is a map on background layer.
On the foreground there is a form in which user enters location.
After he hits enter, map is panning and zooming to specified location.

All I want to do is hide foreground layer AFTER:
1. Map is zoomed
2. Map is panned
3. All tiles are loaded

The problem is that when typed location is very close to starting location, there is no "tilesloaded" event triggered because map panned only few pixels. So I can't depend on "tilesloaded" event.

I can't also depend on "bounds_changed" or "idle" event because they trigger BEFORE all tiles loads.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: You solved your own problem - add the `bounds_changed` or `idle` event listeners inside the `tilesloaded` event callback.

Comment: Unfortunately, `tilesloaded` not always fires. When map's movement is tiny then no tiles are loaded thus no `tilesloaded` is fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may:

1. listen for the `tilesloaded`-event and hide the form when it fires
2. to catch the case where `tilesloaded` didn't fire store the bounds(when opening the form) in a variable. Observe the `bounds_changed` -event and check if the difference(in screen-pixels) between the northeast/southwest of the stored bounds and the current bounds is less than 256(that's the size of a tile). When it does you may assume that there are no tiles to load,  trigger the `tilesloaded`-event immediately.