# Google Maps API loading new tiles event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tiles

Is there an event that let's us know that the Google Map has started to load new tiles? I know that I can key off the tilesloaded event to know that it has FINISHED loading, but I have numerous custom tile layers that would be too cumbersome to track if those tiles have already been loaded (cached) and just toggled. If the map has an event that it finished loading tiles, shouldn't they also include an event that they have started to load new tiles?

My ultimate goal is to give the user an indication that the tile layers are still loading as on-the-fly generation of some tiles can take a little time.

I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26330001/event-on-tiles-start-loading-in-google-maps-v3), but it doesn't address multiple custom tile layers that can be toggled on and off.